# Little help with this "date" function

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, datetime

I have this to select a date from a mysql db, and compare it to an array of month-names in swedish language.

```
$monthnames = array("","Januari","Februari","Mars","April","Maj","Juni","Juli","Augusti","September","Oktober","November","December");

$postdate = $monthnames[date("n", strtotime( $row['modify_date'] ))];
//Outputs something like '12 Februari'
```

Here is the prob, I want to check the $postdate variable and change it to "Today", "Yesterday" and "Day before yesterday" according to the date, how can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you're using timestamps to store dates in the database:**

You can have preset intervals like:

```
$day = mktime(0,0,0,2,1,2001)-mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2001);
```

And you can compare the time now - timestamps/dates you have in the database with those intervals.

For example, let's say $dbTime contains a timestamp fetched with mysql:

```
$time = time() - $dbTime;
if($time<$day)
   echo 'posted today';
elseif($time<($day*2))
   echo 'posted yesterday';
```

etc etc.

Then you can use PHP's Date function to echo hrs, minutes, secs, or dates, if they are larger than your predefined intervals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such in-built function in PHP. You got to do calculations, the `mktime` function can be your friend in this case.

```
if (date of $timenow == date of $timepost) { today; }
else if (date of $timenow - 24h == date of $timepost) { yesterday; }
etc.
```

Be aware about summer/winter time change, timezones etc. so try to use `mktime()`

http://php.net/date